# How to extract a string using regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

Suppose I have the following text

`for (;;);{"__ar":1,"__sf":"k","payload":null,"domops":[["appendContent","^div.fbProfileBrowserListContainer",true,{"__html":"\u003Cdiv class=\"fbProfileBrowserList expandedList\" id=\"100008123852509\">\u003Cul class=\"uiList clearfix _5bbv _4kg _704 _4ks\">\u003Cli class=\"fbProfileBrowserListItem\">\u003Cdiv class=\"clearfix _5qo4\">\u003Ca class=\"_8o _8t lfloat _ohe\" href=\"https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/tasvirmanepal\/?fref=pb\" tabindex=\"-1\" aria-hidden=\"true\">\u003Cimg class=\"_s0 _rw img\" src=\"https:\/\/fb-s-b-a.akamaihd.net\/h-ak-xta1\/v\/t1.0-1\/c13.0.50.50\/p50x50\/12246747_952307471472706_3389977056619055535_n.jpg?oh=fdcd99bd098ad7d60b67701358bdbc97&amp;oe=58D45D87&amp;__gda__=1489984135_7befa40c475cf7f2a6aa021e97d7f429\" alt=\"\" \/>\u003C\/a>\u003Cdiv class=\"clearfix _42ef\">\u003Cdiv class=\"_6a rfloat _ohf\">\u003Cdiv class=\"_6a _6b\" style=\"height:50px\">\u003C\/div>\u003Cdiv class=\"_6a _6b\">\u003Cdiv class=\"_5t4x\">\u003Cspan`

Now , I want to extract string like

`src=\"https:\/\/fb-s-b-a.akamaihd.net\/h-ak-xta1\/v\/t1.0-1\/c13.0.50.50\/p50x50\/12246747_952307471472706_3389977056619055535_n.jpg?oh=fdcd99bd098ad7d60b67701358bdbc97&amp;oe=58D45D87&amp;__gda__=1489984135_7befa40c475cf7f2a6aa021e97d7f429\"`

Comment: Please share the code you have so far and why it does not provide the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

A regex works with logic, first define the logic then write the regex.

say:

- The match is between double quotes, and doesnt contain quotes?
- The match is preceded by `src=\"`

on a website like http://regexr.com/ you can easily test your regex.

This is a possible regex: `src=\\\"[^"]*"` but it wont help you with corner cases.

it basically matches everything that starts with `src\"` and then takes any (zero or more) character except double quote `"` and then also includes the double quote.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```js
const regex = /src=\\"[^"]*?\\"/g;
const str = `for (;;);{"__ar":1,"__sf":"k","payload":null,"domops":[["appendContent","^div.fbProfileBrowserListContainer",true,{"__html":"\\u003Cdiv class=\\"fbProfileBrowserList expandedList\\" id=\\"100008123852509\\">\\u003Cul class=\\"uiList clearfix _5bbv _4kg _704 _4ks\\">\\u003Cli class=\\"fbProfileBrowserListItem\\">\\u003Cdiv class=\\"clearfix _5qo4\\">\\u003Ca class=\\"_8o _8t lfloat _ohe\\" href=\\"https:\\/\\/www.facebook.com\\/tasvirmanepal\\/?fref=pb\\" tabindex=\\"-1\\" aria-hidden=\\"true\\">\\u003Cimg class=\\"_s0 _rw img\\" src=\\"https:\\/\\/fb-s-b-a.akamaihd.net\\/h-ak-xta1\\/v\\/t1.0-1\\/c13.0.50.50\\/p50x50\\/12246747_952307471472706_3389977056619055535_n.jpg?oh=fdcd99bd098ad7d60b67701358bdbc97&amp;oe=58D45D87&amp;__gda__=1489984135_7befa40c475cf7f2a6aa021e97d7f429\\" alt=\\"\\" \\/>\\u003C\\/a>\\u003Cdiv class=\\"clearfix _42ef\\">\\u003Cdiv class=\\"_6a rfloat _ohf\\">\\u003Cdiv class=\\"_6a _6b\\" style=\\"height:50px\\">\\u003C\\/div>\\u003Cdiv class=\\"_6a _6b\\">\\u003Cdiv class=\\"_5t4x\\">\\u003Cspan`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```